# VBA Copying two ranges at the same time "Next without For" error

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code below where i am copying some range from a worksheet to another one. The section in ** is where i believe an error. I am trying to copy two ranges there and i get 
"Next without For" error. If i copy only one range, it works fine. Any idea what i'm doing wrong ?

```
Set tempWB = Application.Workbooks.Open(vrtSelectedItem) 'This OPENS the reference workbook

                   With mainWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B16:B30")

                    tempWB.Sheets("Sheet5").Range("B16:B30").Resize(.Rows.Count, _
                                               .Columns.Count).Value = .Value

                   Set tempWB = Application.Workbooks.Open(vrtSelectedItem) 'This OPENS the reference workbook



                   **With mainWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B16:B30")
                    tempWB.Sheets("Sheet5").Range("B16:B30").Resize(.Rows.Count, _
                                               .Columns.Count).Value = .Value

                    With mainWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D16:D30")
                    tempWB.Sheets("Sheet5").Range("D16:D30").Resize(.Rows.Count, _
                                               .Columns.Count).Value = .Value**

                    End With

                    tempWB.Save 'save and close the reference workbook
                    tempWB.Close

           Next vrtSelectedItem

        Else 'The user pressed Cancel.
        End If
    End With

    Set fd = Nothing 'Set the object variable to Nothing.
End Sub


                    End With

                    tempWB.Save 'save and close the reference workbook
                    tempWB.Close

           Next vrtSelectedItem

        Else 'The user pressed Cancel.
        End If
    End With

    Set fd = Nothing 'Set the object variable to Nothing.
End Sub
```

Comment: You are nesting With blocks. I think that is why it is complaining. This code is also incomplete since i dont see and `Sub` declarded and you have two `End Sub` in code.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem may be that you have a `With` statement nested inside other `With` statements without proper closing of each `With` statement.

While nested `With` statements are acceptable, members of outer `With` blocks are masked so you need to provide a fully qualified object reference if you are referring to a member of a object of an outer `With` block.

Try it without using the `With` statements, or just properly closing your `With` blocks.

Answer (score 0):

You code is incomplete so this could be incorrect. But take this piece of code for example. You have multiple `With` Statements without an equal amount of `End With`.

```
With mainWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B16:B30")

tempWB.Sheets("Sheet5").Range("B16:B30").Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value

Set tempWB = Application.Workbooks.Open(vrtSelectedItem) 'This OPENS the reference workbook

**With mainWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B16:B30")
tempWB.Sheets("Sheet5").Range("B16:B30").Resize(.Rows.Count, _
                           .Columns.Count).Value = .Value

With mainWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D16:D30")
tempWB.Sheets("Sheet5").Range("D16:D30").Resize(.Rows.Count, _
                           .Columns.Count).Value = .Value**

End With
```

You need to do something like this.

```
With mainWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B16:B30")
    tempWB.Sheets("Sheet5").Range("B16:B30").Resize(.Rows.Count, _
                               .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
End With

Set tempWB = Application.Workbooks.Open(vrtSelectedItem) 'This OPENS the reference workbook

With mainWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B16:B30")
    tempWB.Sheets("Sheet5").Range("B16:B30").Resize(.Rows.Count, _
                           .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
    tempWB.Sheets("Sheet5").Range("D16:D30").Resize(.Rows.Count, _
                           .Columns.Count).Value = .Value**
End With
```

End the first `with` with and `end with` and since you had 2 `With` declarations that are the same we can consolidate them into one and terminate properly. It is also good for to indent code in blocks for readability.

Comment: Thanks Matt but aren't we opening the same workbook twice in this case, i get an error saying the workbook is already open

Comment: I only see the one call to Open the workbook. Its only there since you had it included in your code. Do you have another call somewhere else? Or was the workbook not closed properly?

Answer (score 0):

something like this if you factor out the "copy values" into a separate Sub:

```
    '...
    Dim tempWB As Workbook

    Set tempWB = Application.Workbooks.Open(vrtSelectedItem)

    CopyValues mainWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B16:B30"), _
               tempWB.Sheets("Sheet5").Range("B16")

    CopyValues mainWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D16:D30"), _
               tempWB.Sheets("Sheet5").Range("D16")

    tempWB.Save
    tempWB.Close
    '...

    'copy values only from one range to another
    Sub CopyValues(rngSrc As Range, rngDest As Range)
        With rngSrc
            rngDest.Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
        End With
    End Sub
```